# Templated Class has a Circular Dependency

Tags: c++, templates

I have two classes.  One is a management class, which stores a bunch of worker classes.  The workers are actually a templated class.

```
#include "worker.h"    
class Management {

     private: 
      worker<type1> worker1;
      worker<type2> worker2;
      ...

};
```

The problem arises due to the fact that the templated classes needs to use Management.

Example:

```
class Worker{
   ...
};

#include "Worker.inl"
```

The Worker inl file:

```
#include "Management.h"  //Circular Dependency!

Worker::Worker(){
    //Management is accessed here
    Management mgmt1();
    mgmt1.doSomething(); //Can't use that forward declaration!
}
...
```

Normally you would forward declare Management.h in the Worker header file, and call it a day.  Sadly, since the class is templated, it is always going to get included.

I guess you can claim that the design is bad, since a templated class shouldn't be templated if it needs to know this sort of information, but it is what it is, and I have to work with it.

You can also view this question as a microcosm of office life.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with templates... possibly rename and re-tag?

Comment: @Oli: If it has nothing to do with templates, then it's a duplicate several times over.

Comment: In the code you posted, `Worker` constructor creates a `Management` object that contains two `Worker`s, whose constructor is called and that creates... Are you sure that you want to do this? what is the real problem that you want to tackle? There may be better solutions than the approach you are taking.

Comment: In the real code the Management class is holds information used by the worker, and the worker holds a pointer to it.  I instantiated the Management class within the Worker to emulate this.  I cannot post the real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no actual members of `Management` are referred by worker.inl (i.e. only pointers/references to `Management`), you could forward declare it:

```
class Management;

Worker::Worker(){
    Management* mgmt1; // fine
    Management& mgmt2; // fine
    //mgmt1 = new Management(); // won't compile with forward declaration
    //mgmt2.doSomething(); // won't compile with forward declaration
}
```

Otherwise your only option may be to move the method implementations into a cpp file, not included in the headers.

Note that `Worker` can not be forward declared, since it is contained by value in `Management`:

```
  worker<type1> worker1;
```

thus the compiler needs to know its full definition at this point.

You should also consider putting the two class definitions into the same header file, to express that they are interdependent, thus form a *component*.

Comment: Right, some action needs to be done on the Management class.  Exactly like mgmt2.doSomething().  This is why I needed the .h file.  Sounds to me that the only way around this is a bit of a rewrite.  Oh Joy.

Comment: Actually, you can use value types here -- it need not be pointers. Example: http://codepad.org/gtLynfPC

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how templates change this. Forward declare to remove circular dependencies in headers.

EDIT: Sorry, I reversed this initially. The second example is correct though (see [CodePad](http://codepad.org/18JaTYVV))

<s>template class worker;</s>

```
class Managment
{
    worker<type1> a;
    worker<type2> b;
};

template<typename T> class worker
{
///... okay to use class Managment here.
};
```

```
#include <iostream>

class type1 {};
class type2 {};

class Managment;

template<typename T> struct worker
{
    inline void doSomethingElse();
};

class Managment
{
    worker<type1> a;
    worker<type2> b;
public:
    inline void doSomething();
};


inline void Managment::doSomething()
{
    a.doSomethingElse();
    b.doSomethingElse();
}

template<typename T>
inline void worker<T>::doSomethingElse()
{
    std::cout << "Hello!";
}

int main()
{
    Managment mgmt;
    mgmt.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: AFAIK the compiler needs to know the exact size of a `worker` object - thus its complete class definition - to resolve this.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your code snippet, but if your first line is simply a forward declaration of `worker<T>`, then the compiler won't know how big a `Management` object is.

Comment: @Oli: I don't see why the compiler needs to know how big a management object is at that point -- sure, Worker would need to be a complete type in order to *instantiate* management, but as far as I knew it wasn't required at declaration time -- it's just a declaration. But you are correct in that it didn't compile. I've updated my answer with a compiling example.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this with clean syntax & no runtime overhead is to use an interface. Basically, all the operations that `Worker` needs to perform on `Management`, put into some interface like this:

```
interface IManagementOps
{
public:
    void DoStuff() = 0;
};

class Worker
{
    IManagementOps* pOps;
    ...     
};

class Management : public IManagementOps
{
    ...
};
```

Please be careful that your design is good though and that it's actually appropriate for `Worker` to be doing things with `Management`.

Comment: @tenfour: there will be a runtime overhead (`virtual has a cost`) however I agree it's highly unlikely to be noticeable.

Comment: @Matthieu, the runtime overhead can be avoided if you never use pointers or references. If you are calling a member of a concrete object, the compiler knows which member will be called and bypasses the virtual lookup.

Comment: @Mark: but that would defeat the point of using an interface!

Comment: you can also use `__declspec(novtable)`. The point is to bundle the operations that `Worker` uses into one interface, as a matter of organization. Actually I prefer Billy ONeal's solution usually, but sometimes the interface method is cleaner too, depending on the context. `interface` I think is a MS-only thing, but yea you could similarly just use a `class`.

Comment: @tenfour: Yes, `interface` is not and has never been standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to avoid the compile error due to recursive inclusion.

But to solve the problem, i believe the solution is to use forward declarations and use Pointers/References when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

if you actually need  to access Management from worker class you can add Management as additional template parameter to worker. 
I.e. something like this:

```
template <class mngmnt, int type >
class worker{
  mngmnt* p_mngmnt;  
public:
  char* getManagementName(){return p_mngmnt->management_name;}
};


class Management {

public:
 char* management_name;

 private: 
   worker<Management,1> worker1;
   worker<Management,2> worker2;

};
```